# Separating similar values from array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array with values 0,1,2. I want to separate them in different arrays and plot them. How can I do that?

```
for i in range(2):
    if i==0
         z = [i]
    elif i==1
         y = [i]
    else
         w = [i]
```

this is what i tried

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid Python, and doesn't have anything to do with plotting; what were you trying to do with it?

Comment: i didnt get it....i am new to this field..kindly explain in simpler way

Comment: i know its not a valid way, but i am not able to separate thesevalues in different arrays

Answer (score 0):

just use the histogram function from pyplot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.randint(0,3,100)
plt.hist(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If that's actually what image was looking for you should be an archaeologist, not a programmer.